# Google Analytics plugin for Peachpie wp-dotnet project

Tags: wordpress, asp.net-core, peachpie

Has anyone successfully used Google Analytics plugin on Peachpie wp-dotnet project? So far I've tried "googleanalytics v2.4.1-preview5" and "google-analytics-for-wordpress v7.14.0-preview5". Both failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I've installed wk-google-analytics package and it worked out without any issues. Below is the link:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wk-google-analytics/